# UISwitch in static cell flickers when table reloaded

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a small UITableView with static cells, one of which contains a UISwitch.  I reload the table when the switch's state changes, since it's state affects the rest of the table and the table is quite small.  Unfortunately, the switch flickers when redrawn.  Specifically, when I move the switch from off to on, it shows on, then goes from some halfway state to on again when the table is reloaded.  Has anyone experienced this or have a suggestion as to how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the tableview, it rebuilds all its cells.
Depending on the exact code building those cells, this kind of behaviour can be noticed.

I would recommend not calling the reload method, but instead, figuring out which rows need to be refreshed and calling  `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. This will lead to much better animation behaviour;

Additionnaly, if some cells needs to be added or deleted, you can figure out whose positions those are and use `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` or `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

[Here's the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) on managing cell insertion and deletion

Comment: thanks, but those calls don't work with static tables, and i'm not sure it would help in this instance, anyway, since the switch would still have to be redrawn.